# How do I activate or set focus on program windows by hovering over their taskbar icons?

Tags: windows-7

I currently have it to where a window will come to foreground on hover. How can I make it do the same with the tabs in taskbar? I don't care about previews, I want the window to come into foreground when I hover over a taskbar tab(ie chrome).

---

Another way to ask this.... 
I have `Activate a window by hovering over it with a mouse` enabled from Ease of Access Center.

How can I apply/emulate this behavior to the tabs in the taskbar?

Note: My tabs are `never combined`.

Comment: When you hover over what?

Comment: The tabs...like if I am running chrome and there is a chrome tab for that session. Instead of having to click on the tab to bring it into foreground, I would like to be able to just hover over it.... just like I can with a window.

Comment: Please add that information to your question. Without it the question does not make sense. Also, you recognize that the Chrome application and the Windows operating system are different and do not behave in the same way? Finally, what happens when you hover your mouse over application previews on your Windows taskbar? It's been a few months since I work on a Windows 7 computer, but I believe that this brought the application window to the foreground.

Comment: @music2myear When you hover over an application preview in Win7, that window gets temporarily brought to the foreground, and all other windows go temporarily transparent. You have to actually click on the preview to keep it in the foreground.

Comment: So you want the hover action to be the same as the click action? That's likely going to require some UI modification likely in the form of a UI mod application that handles this custom behavior. Also, just a tip, you're the first person I've seen refer to the icons in the taskbar as "Tabs". Changing this to a more commonly used term may further improve the clarity of your question.

Comment: maybe just try using `WinKey` + `Tab`, it will show you previews for all the windows you have in your taskbar.